# List property ignored by controller if 0 index is missing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I'm building a webform in c# .net mvc using mongodb to store information.  The form works with a company object that has a property that is a List of Addresses, called addressdata. When the form is submitted, the company object is sent to the controller and then upserted into MongoDB. The input names take the form

```
<input type="text" name="Company.addressdata[a].city" />
```

Where "a" is the index in the list. This all works great! The list of address objects is created upon submission and inserts into mongoDB.

However, I just added the ability to delete addresses, and now I'm running into trouble. I have noticed that when a user deletes the first row, all the rows after are lost. So, if they delete the 0 index, the Company object will not populate the list of Addresses and thus they will not go into MongoDB.

Is there a way to work around this? Is this how it's designed to work? It seems like too much to renumber all of the following rows with the new index, but is that what it takes? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, that's by design. The indexes must start from 0, or you have to define your own indexes for each of them with a special element.

This article shows an example of that: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

```
<form method="post" action="/Home/Create">

    <input type="hidden" name="products.Index" value="cold" />
    <input type="text" name="products[cold].Name" value="Beer" />
    <input type="text" name="products[cold].Price" value="7.32" />

    <input type="hidden" name="products.Index" value="123" />
    <input type="text" name="products[123].Name" value="Chips" />
    <input type="text" name="products[123].Price" value="2.23" />

    <input type="hidden" name="products.Index" value="caliente" />
    <input type="text" name="products[caliente].Name" value="Salsa" />
    <input type="text" name="products[caliente].Price" value="1.23" />

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

So you have options, either:

1. Update indices when deleting, or
2. Define arbitrary indices

Comment: Excellent! Arbitrary Indices was the way to go. Thanks!!